# how to retrieve item's data from DataGrid the item is selected WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In a WPF app I have a `DataGrid`, containing items of type **Customer**

I need to get the customer's information, when it is clicked in the datagrid

I've tried the code below in the `SelectedCellsChanged`, `DataGridCell.Selected` and `DataGridRow.Selected`, but I get the same errors:

> Customer customer = (Customer)datagrid1.SelectedItem;
> MessageBox.Show(customer.Name);

The error => can not convert from type `System.Data.DataRowView` to `BE.Customer`

Or like this:

> Customer customer = datagrid1.SelecteItem as Customer;
> MessageBox.Show(customer.Name);

And I get a runtime error, which says that the `customer` is null, and it isn't set to an instance of an object

Comment: How do you set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid`?

Comment: my Read method returns a datatable, so i set the ItemsSource like this:

Comment: datagrid1.ItemsSource = (bll.Read()).DefaultView;

Comment: Then `SelectedItem` is a `DataRowView` and nothing else: `var customer = (DataRowView)datagrid1.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(drv["Name"].ToString());`

Comment: BRO
I'm a beginner programmer
I've been searching all over internet for a solution
I watched different "COURSES" on XAML and ...
but nothing
tnx a lot ♥

Comment: I just have one more question 
as you see above, I'm using a `DataTable` to fill the `DataGrid` there is this id property which I don't want to be visible in `DataGrid` do you know how I can do that? I've used this code in the `Loaded` event of my window:
`datagrid1.ItemsSource = bll.Read().DefaultView;

datagrid1.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`
but I get this run-time error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.'